Identity column behavior different in 2 versions of Teradata?
I have the following SQL script
CREATE MULTISET TABLE "test" 
(
"TestID" BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
    (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647  NO CYCLE) NOT NULL,
"Version" VARCHAR (30)
);

When I run it against Teradata Express (17.20.3.02) it executes successfully and creates the table, although it implicitly creates a Primary Index behind the scenes for the TestID column. However, the same exact script run on another Teradata instance hosted by ClearSpace (17.20.3.23) returns the following error:

Syntax error: Identity Column in a NoPI table is unsupported.

I get that I could add a section in to cover the auto generate column but did the behavior change between versions? SQL scripts that worked before, no longer do on the hosted version?

When the PI is not defined in the DDL there's a system default which is switched in the Clearscape environment from "NUPI on 1st column" to NoPI table

Would it be wrong to add ...) PRIMARY INDEX (TestId) at the end of it;?

Yeah looks like a system default and I can add the Primary Index at the end just wasn't sure why the behavior was different. Thanks!!
